# Word for a commonly encountered scenario

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes an abstract process that is encountered frequently? For example, every time I get into a car, I start it by turning the key. The car and the key might be different in every single scenario, but the process is still 'get into car, turn key'. I was thinking *idiom*, but that doesn't really seem to fit.

Answer (score 4):

The word *routine* comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for the word [procedure](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/procedure?region=us&q=procedure).

Answer (score 1):

How about `behavior?` I can't find a good reference to the definition of the word that describes what you're asking about, but I believe it's used this way all the time.

Answer (score 1):

A [*habit*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/habit) is defined as "a recurrent, often unconscious pattern of behavior that is acquired through frequent repetition."